# Javascript form submits but not with all appended form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google places auto completion search bar. The post data from the form is read in Symfony. The search bar works fine but the user has to click on a place in the list, so I made it that if the user hits enter it'd simulate a down arrow and select the first suggestion.

If a user clicks on a place in the list I do a jQuery form.append to add the lat/lng
If a user hits enter I can see the form.append happening in inspect elements but the fields are not showing up in the post data.

Below is the code that handles the auto completion and simulated down arrow

```
window.autocomplete = null;
    const form = $('#search-form');

    function initAutocomplete() {
        var pac_input = document.getElementById('search-input');

        (function pacSelectFirst(input) {
            // store the original event binding function
            var _addEventListener = (input.addEventListener) ? input.addEventListener : input.attachEvent;

            function addEventListenerWrapper(type, listener) {
                // Simulate a 'down arrow' keypress on hitting 'return' when no pac suggestion is selected,
                // and then trigger the original listener.
                if (type === "keydown") {
                    var orig_listener = listener;
                    listener = function (event) {
                        var suggestion_selected = $(".pac-item-selected").length > 0;
                        if (event.which === 13 && !suggestion_selected) {
                            var simulated_downarrow = $.Event("keydown", {
                                keyCode: 40,
                                which: 40
                            });
                            orig_listener.apply(input, [simulated_downarrow]);
                        }
                        orig_listener.apply(input, [event]);
                    };
                }
                _addEventListener.apply(input, [type, listener]);
            }

            input.addEventListener = addEventListenerWrapper;
            input.attachEvent = addEventListenerWrapper;

            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,
                {types: ['geocode']});

            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

        })(pac_input);
    }
```

Below is the function fillInAddress which adds the fields.

```
function fillInAddress() {
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place)
        let lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        let lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        let searchplace = place.formatted_address;
        let searchplaceElement = $('#searchplace');
        if (!searchplaceElement.length) {
            form.append("<input id='searchplace' name='searchplace' type='hidden' value='" + searchplace + "'>")
            form.append("<input id='lat' name='lat' type='hidden' value='" + lat + "'>")
            form.append("<input id='lng' name='lng' type='hidden' value='" + lng + "'>")
        } else {
            searchplaceElement.val(searchplace);
            $('#lat').val(lat);
            $('#lng').val(lng);
        }
}
```

Below is the HTML form part.

```
        <form action="/restaurants" id="search-form" method="post">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input id="search-input" class="form-control shadow-none" type="text" placeholder="Zoeken op adres of postcode">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Zoeken</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have to add I'm not a real good export on jQuery or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard submit button only submits form fields that were initially loaded. Fields that were added after DOM loads, have to get submitted manually for example  like this:

```
$('#search-form).on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize());
});
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for telling me the problem! This doesn't submit the form though I can now see that the simulated down arrow works and it fills in the field! But the $.post does not make the redirect to the other page, which I need. Do I then want to make it with $.ajax and then within that $.mobile.changePage?

Comment: `$.post` is shorthand for a post with `$.ajax` . You could for example use the `$.post` callback to redirect after the post is done or if you want more control, use the ajax `success`, `error` and `done` callbacks

Comment: $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function () {
                    return window.location.href = '/restaurants';
}); 

this is what I do or location.replace or without return it does redirect but it looks like the form submits again and the post is empty thus getting a "no restaurants found" on the page. What it needs to do is post the appended data and then go to the url with that data. Your answers works though, everything is in the post as I can see in inspect element